# Problema con función isoweek en R

Tags: r, date

Estoy utilizando la función `isoweek` para determinar a qué semana del año pertenece cada día desde el `1-1-2015` hasta el `31-10-2018` el problema es que del `1-1-2016` al `3-1-2016` me los coloca como semana 53 del año 2015 y comienza a contar la semana 1 del 2016 hasta el 4-1-2016 intenté hacerlo por separado

```
week2015<-isoweek(data$Fecha[data$Año=="2015"])
week2016<-isoweek(data$Fecha[data$Año=="2016"])
```

pero el problema persiste, ¿alguna solución que se les ocurra?

Answer (score 2):

Es que ese es justamente el comportamiento natural de un  [`isoweek`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). La primer particularidad de la ISO 8601, es cual se considera la primer semana, se sigue la siguiente lógica (de la wikipedia):

La definición ISO 8601 para la semana 01 del año, es la semana que contiene el primer jueves del año gregoriano. Las siguientes definiciones basadas en las propiedades de esta semana son mutuamente equivalentes, ya que la semana ISO comienza el lunes:

- Es la primera semana con una mayoría (4 o más) de sus días en enero.
- Su primer día es el lunes más cercano al 1 de enero.
- Tiene el 4 de enero. Por lo tanto, la primera semana más temprana posible se * extiende desde el lunes 29 de diciembre (año gregoriano anterior) hasta el domingo 4 de enero, mientras que la primera semana más tardía se extiende desde el lunes 4 de enero hasta el domingo 10 de enero.
- Tiene el primer día laborable del año, si los sábados, domingos y el 1 de enero no son días laborables.

Si el 1 de enero es un lunes, martes, miércoles o jueves, es en la semana 01. Si el 1 de enero es un viernes, forma parte de la semana 53 del año anterior. Si es sábado, forma parte de la última semana del año anterior, que se numera 52 en un año común y 53 en un año bisiesto. Si es domingo, forma parte de la semana 52 del año anterior.

Lo que ocurre es que se considera las semana 53 que comenzó el lunes 28 del 2015 y finalizaría el domingo 3 de enero de 2016.

Lo podemos verificar:

```
library(lubridate)

# Hasta el domingo 3 se considera la semana 53 del 2015
fecha <- dmy('03-01-2016')
c(isoweek(fecha), weekdays(fecha))

[1] "53"      "domingo"

# Ahora si el lunes 4 se considera comienza la semana 1 del 2016
fecha <- dmy('04-01-2016')
c(isoweek(fecha), weekdays(fecha))

[1] "1"     "lunes"
```

Pareciera ser que lo que buscas es usar más bien la función [`week()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/week), por ejemplo

```
fecha <- dmy('01-01-2016')
c(week(fecha), weekdays(fecha))

[1] "1"       "viernes"
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1883/ es todo lo que puedo agregar...

Comment: Lo que me parece extraño es esto
    isoweek(data$Fecha[data$Año=="2015"])  #retorna
     [1]  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2

Comment: Lo que me parece extraño es que si isoweek() funciona naturalmente de esa forma cuando agrego
    isoweek(data$Fecha[data$Año=="2015"])  #retorna
     [1]  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2     ##es decir entiende que 2015-1-1 es la primer semana del 2015 y no la continuación de la semana 53 del 2014, pero el cambio a 2016 no lo hace, he probado con week(data$Fecha) #retorna [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  , que es algo que no deseo pues mis semanas tienen que ir de lunes a domingo y reiniciarse a 1 cada cambio de año

Comment: Efectivamente es lo que dices, el enlace en la wikipedia lo detalla un poco más, pero me falto indicarlo en la respuesta, la primer semana ISO se considera la del primer jueves del año. En el caso del 1/1/2015 es justamente jueves y es la primer semana del año. Ahora edito mi respuesta

Comment: @mpaladino, ja ja..

Comment: Gracias @pmoracho